# Tomcat doesn't start in docker container because it can't create log files

Tags: tomcat, docker

I'm trying to run Tomcat in docker container on behalf of tomcat user.
Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest
...
RUN groupadd -g743 tomcat
RUN useradd -u734 -M -s /bin/nologin -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
...
RUN chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat/
RUN chmod o+rwx /opt/tomcat
...
USER tomcat
CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I run the container in interactive mode under tomcat user:

```
bash-4.2$ whoami
tomcat
```

But Tomcat fails to start due to following:

```
21-May-2016 21:55:34.262 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open Failed to open access log file [/opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2016-05-21.txt]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2016-05-21.txt (Permission denied) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

tomcat user owns the /opt/tomcat folder and all its subfolders

```
bash-4.2$ ls -la /opt/tomcat/
total 120
drwxr-xrwx 16 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 21 21:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root    4096 May 21 21:54 ..
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat 57092 May 11 21:45 LICENSE
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat  1804 May 11 21:45 NOTICE
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat  6708 May 11 21:45 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat 15946 May 11 21:45 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x---  2 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 21 21:54 bin
drwx------  2 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 21 21:54 conf
drwxr-x---  2 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 21 21:54 lib
drwxr-x---  2 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 11 21:44 logs
drwxr-x---  2 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 21 21:54 temp
drwxr-x--- 12 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 21 21:54 webapps
drwxr-x---  2 tomcat tomcat  4096 May 11 21:44 work
```

but I have no idea why it's forbidden for the user to create files in his folder

```
bash-4.2$ touch /opt/tomcat/logs/test.txt
touch: cannot touch '/opt/tomcat/logs/test.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Does the account (I believe your tomcat user) that is running the script have the rights on the folder to create files?  I'm guessing that this is your issue.

Comment: Once inside the container did you switch user before executing the touch command?

Comment: Remove this:-g743, this:-u734 and o+rwx. Try again, should work! Afterwards modify and restrict with chmod only, should be enough, less side effects.